# How to control columns position? bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I got these 4 columns inside a row and when I'm resizing the window their positioning is awkward.

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="row">
      <div id="1" class="col-md-3">
      ...
      </div>
      <div id="2" class="col-md-3">
      ...
      </div>
      <div id="3" class="col-md-3">
      ...
      </div>
      <div id="4" class="col-md-3">
      ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to move the columns one by one when resizing the window, instead of the built in bootstrap function, where all of them move down at the same time.

The correct positioning should be:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4

1 - 2 - 3
4

1 - 2
3
4

1
2
3
4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the inner divs to:

```
  <div id="1" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  ...
  </div>
```